# In a family of sets $F=2^S$ for a set $S$, are $f(\cup X) = \cup\{f(\{x\}): x \in X\}$ and $f(x \cup y) = f(x)\cup f(y)$ equivalent conditions on $f$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm interested in [algebras of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets) and equipping them with function symbols and interpretations.

Let $X$ be a set. Let $F$ be the family of sets $2^X$. Let $f$ be a binary function symbol with an interpretation associated with $F$

One fairly natural condition that one may want to impose on a function in this setting is something roughly analogous to "distributivity", the idea being that, given a pair of sets $(U, V)$, $f$ is completely determined by what it does to the singletons of $U$ and $V$, i.e.

$$ f \;\text{is distributive} \iff \forall U, V. \left(f(U,V) = \bigcup_{(u,v) \in U\times V} f(\{u\}, \{v\})\right) $$

I'm curious whether we can impose this condition on $f$ in a nice "quantifier-free" way, i.e. whether something like the following captures the intended meaning of distributivity.

$$ f(x \cup y, z \cup w) = f(x, z) \cup f(x, w) \cup f(y, z) \cup f(y, w) $$

Let's also impose $f(\varnothing) = \varnothing$ explicitly for good measure.

The condition above certainly works when $X$ is finite.

If $X$ is $\mathbb{N}$, I'm not sure whether repeatedly *splitting off* the smallest remaining natural number works as a technique for showing that $f$ is distributive, but I think it does. Suppose $g$ is a unary function.

Let $a_1, a_2, \cdots$ be the values of a set $L$ in order.

We know the following.

$$g(L) = g(a_1) \cup g(\cup\{a_2, a_3, \cdots\}) = g(a_1) \cup g(a_2) \cup g(\cup\{a_3, a_4 \cdots\}) = g(a_1) \cup g(a_2) \cup g(a_3) \cup g(\cup\{a_4, a_5, \cdots\})$$

If this process were to fail at some point, it must fail after finitely many steps, which would contradict the hypothesis. Therefore it never fails for any set $L$.

However, for the general case I'm not sure and I'm not confident in the argument for $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Just take
$$
f(U,V) = \begin{cases}
\emptyset &\text{if $U$ and $V$ are finite,}\\
\Bbb N&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$